# Case insensitive validate_exclusion

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a list of strings that should not be used as usernames. I see that there is `validate_exclusion` in ecto but I don't think there is a way to do this in case insensitive. Is there a way to do this? `validate_format` with regex perhaps?

- note: I'd like to avoid simply downcasing my user names.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `validate_change` instead.

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  ...
  |> validate_change(:username, validate_restricted_usernames)
end

@restricted_usernames ~w(about faq...)
def validate_restricted_usernames do
  fn :username, username ->
    case Enum.any?(@restricted_usernames, fn x -> x == String.downcase(username) end) do
      true -> [username: "username is already taken."]
      false -> []
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Instead of `Enum.any?(@restricted_usernames, fn x -> x == String.downcase(username) end)` can do `String.downcase(username) in @restricted_usernames`

Comment: Nice suggestion @OleksandrAvoyants

Answer (score 0):

You said (in answer) that you have used `validate_change`,
but you actually didn't.
Here is variant with [validate_change/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_change/3):

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  # ...
  |> validate_change(:username, fn :username, username  ->
    if String.downcase(username) in @restricted_usernames, do: [username: "is restricted"], else: [] end)
end
```